# Mysql foreign key constraint violation when factory builds/creates a new belongs_to

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rspec, associations, factory-bot

**I have two models:**

```
class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'language_id'

  has_many :results_footers
end

class ResultsFooter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :language
end
```

**a factory:**

```
# spec/factories/languages.rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :language do
    sequence(:language_id)
  end
end
```

**a test:**

```
# spec/models/results_footer.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ResultsFooter, :type => :model do
  it 'has a valid factory' do
    create(:results_footer).should be_valid
  end
 end
```

The results_footer table is a mysql table with a fk constraint on it's language_id field.

When I run the test i get:

ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey:
       Mysql2::Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`thing_dev`.`results_footers`, CONSTRAINT `results_footers_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`language_id`) REFERENCES `language` (`language_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE): INSERT INTO `results_footers` (`language_id`, `grade`, `content`, `exam_type_id`) VALUES (1, 'D', 'Hello World', 104)

Of course if I remove the constraint it works. But removing the constraint is not an option.

Odd thing is I've many other tables with similar fk constraints and their associations work.

Whats wrong with my association?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, the answer I sought is here:

https://gist.github.com/myronmarston/61380bb4500b4d85dd3f